# Julia - Incrementally modifying a function with another functions

Tags: function, julia, meta, code-reuse

I'm developing a package in Julia. I was wondering how can one incrementally modify a function depending on parameters given by the user. For example, take a plotting library. I'll define many plot functions, such as scatter, histograms, etc. Now, all these functions can be augmented with a series of parameters, such as "color", "line width", "plot size", etc.

Now, what I'd like to do is something like this:
Depending on the parameters that the user passes, the original plotting function should be modified accordingly:

```
# Original function
function StdPlot(x,y)
   draw(axis1 = x, axis2 = y)
end

if "color" in kwargs
   @add_color(StdPlot)
end
```

Then, the @add_color macro would modify the original function to something like:

```
@add_color(StdPlot):
   x_mod = [x,colorx]
   y_mod = [y,colory]
   draw(axis=x_mod,axis=y_mod)
```